# Word got hidden in cells for long sentence?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

When I write in cell of Excel 2007, and the sentence is long, it is hidden.

I want it to return to next line. Is it possible please ?

As you can see in this screenshot, the Hello world sentence is cut and hidden in the back : 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Right click* on the cell; Choose *Format Cells*; On *Alignment* Tab tick in *Wrap Text*.

Now the text will wrap to a second line inside the same cell.